# Applying deep logistic regression on sparse labels

Tags: logistic, deep-learning, sparse

I have a dataset of 100 000 examples. Only 1% are positive (1000 examples).

I want to predict the probability that a positive event happen.
To do that I have built a 4 layer DNN (Linear W*x+b -> ReLU)with a sigmoid single unit output layer.

I calculate the loss using the mean_squared_error loss function and an AdamOptimizer for backprop.

I observe the following during the learning:
epoch 0:

```
Predictions (0 1)    Labels
0.5  0.5              0
0.5  0.5              0
....
```

After several iterations I can see that the learning is systematically increasing the prediction value for 0, and decrease the one for 1. It goes so far that when I have a positive example appearing it doesn't even detect it.
It looks like that:

```
Predictions (0 1)    Labels
0.88977    0.11023    0
0.88977    0.11023    0
0.88977    0.11023    0
...
0.88977    0.11023    0
0.88977    0.11023    1
0.88977    0.11023    0
```

It looks to me that it only learns to predict the negative example since they represent 99% of my dataset, but do not succeed at all in predicting the positive...

How could I modify this architecture to be able to predict positive examples ?

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to generate data where you dictate the true probabilities, and test that the logistic learning algorithm can recover those.

If the probability estimates are well calibrated, what you are seeing is as expected.  Unless there are smoking gun predictors, you will have the bulk of probabilities towards the end where the outcomes are most frequent.  One other way to check the system is that the mean predicted probability that Y=1 should exactly match the proportion of Y=1.

The problem is with the use of the concept "predict a positive".  The logistic model is a direct continuous probability model and you shouldn't use the words "positive" and "negative" in this context.